# Scoping validation checks in Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

When executing the pipeline `IAssociateCategoryToParentPipeline`, there is a step that checks if there are any validation errors in `CommerceContext.GetMessages()`.

This will cause an update to fail even if the messages were in place before the pipeline was initiated, which seems counterintuitive.

**Question:**

Is there a way to "refresh" the commerce context, or create a clone of it with an empty message list?

**Details:**

- Observed in XC 9.0-Update 1.
- `AssociateCategoryToParentPipeline` calls `AssociateCategoryToParentBlock`, which call `CreateRelatationshipCommand`.
- `CreateRelationshipCommand.Process` calls the static method `Command.PerformTransaction`, and that calls `ValidatateTransaction`.
- ValidationTransaction looks for the existence of a message with a code of "ValidationError", and if one is found, rolls back the transaction. So as long as there are any ValidationErrors in this list, any call to this command, and by extension `AssociateCategoryToParentPipeline`, will fail to persist updates.

Comment: Are you writing an import? Please check https://joost.meijles.com/optimize_catalog_import/ for performance tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest understanding what is an initial issue, that adds this ValidationError message to your context.

However, if you are writing initial import that requires a huge amount of entities to be imported it's better to clean context periodically to free memory.

You can use the following snippet:

```
context.CommerceContext = new CommerceContext(context.CommerceContext.Logger, context.CommerceContext.TelemetryClient)
{
    GlobalEnvironment = context.CommerceContext.GlobalEnvironment,
    Environment = context.CommerceContext.Environment,
    Headers = context.CommerceContext.Headers
};
```

Comment: Validation error was from a "delete relationship" pipeline call that didn't check if the relationship existed.  I agree that should be tightened, but wanted to understand the pattern for isolating these operations. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to use a new CommerceContext for each call.

If that isn’t feasible you can use the clear methods, e.g:

```
 context.CommerceContext.ClearEntities();
 context.CommerceContext.ClearModels();
 context.CommerceContext.ClearObjects();
```